# Pass argument to a backing bean constructor?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, el

Would it be possible to pass argument to a backing bean constructor?

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{WatchfolderEditBean.classifiedObject.servergroupId}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{ServerGroupMgmtBean( false ).objectsAsListItems}" />
</p:selectOneMenu></td>
```

In this case `ServerGroupMgmtBean( false )` should execute a constructor that takes boolean as argument,however, this doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported according [EL specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) and does also not make any sense according [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) which EL is relying upon.

Just subclass the bean or pass it as getter method argument if you really need to.